# Impress - View Presentation changes objects layout

Tags: libreoffice, presentation

I having problems with the 'view presentation mode'. I can see my presentation nicely in the edition mode (1) but when I go to the view presentation mode (F5), some images are changed (background and some others), you can see the screenshots in the urls below.

I am using Format->Page->Format Screen 4:3. I have checked and unchecked 'autofit object to page format', but I have the same bad result.

Any idea? I attach here two screenshots where you can see the difference between editing and the presentation result.

If I export to PDF, the result is ok.

I am using LibreOffice 4.3.52 in Ubuntu.

Any idea about how to solve this?

Thanks,
          Carlos A.

1) Slide using edit mode: [image]

2) Same slide in view presentation mode:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you right click on the slide then select slide->page setup
and in page tab you select paper format 16:9, that should solve your problem.

[image]